# Find lowest value in results set

Tags: php

I am trying to find the cleanest method of turning this set of results into an array and then finding the lowest value.

```
if (!$result) die($conn->error);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $low_score_1 = $row['low_score_1'];
    $low_score_2 = $row['low_score_2'];
    $low_score_3 = $row['low_score_3'];
    $low_score_4 = $row['low_score_4'];
    $low_score_5 = $row['low_score_5'];
    $low_score_6 = $row['low_score_6'];
    $low_score_7 = $row['low_score_7'];
    $low_score_8 = $row['low_score_8'];  

}
```

Comment: $lowest = min($row);

Comment: @Farkie This takes other columns into account as well though. OP might not want that. Like if `ID` would exist in his result

Comment: Put them all into an array, and then min it

Comment: @Loko Then if he wanted that, he should have specified. Either way `$lowest = min(array_column($row, 'col'))` would fix that.

Comment: I just wanna pop all those results into some kind of array or order so i can then find out which is the lowest number in the series...

Comment: In my opinion he kind of specifies it by even making 8 variables or it could be that he's just showing a terrible example.

Comment: So literally all the columns from the `$row` variable?

Comment: @Loko, so that above will output 8 values like: 1, 2.5, 3, 2, 3.75, 1.5, 2, 2.75 or something to that affect it is different every time, so i would like to just find the lowest number

Comment: @PhpDude Yes but if those are literally the only values in the array, then Farkie is right. Use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you want. Its a bit simple and long hand but sometimes thats easier

```
if (!$result) die($conn->error);

// read first row and seed the variables with these values
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$low_score_1 = $row['low_score_1'];
$low_score_2 = $row['low_score_2'];
$low_score_3 = $row['low_score_3'];
$low_score_4 = $row['low_score_4'];
$low_score_5 = $row['low_score_5'];
$low_score_6 = $row['low_score_6'];
$low_score_7 = $row['low_score_7'];
$low_score_8 = $row['low_score_8']; 

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{
    $low_score_1 = ($row['low_score_1'] < $low_score_1) ? $row['low_score_1'] : $low_score_1;
    $low_score_2 = ($row['low_score_2'] < $low_score_2) ? $row['low_score_2'] : $low_score_2;
    $low_score_3 = ($row['low_score_3'] < $low_score_3) ? $row['low_score_3'] : $low_score_3;
    $low_score_4 = ($row['low_score_4'] < $low_score_4) ? $row['low_score_4'] : $low_score_4;
    $low_score_5 = ($row['low_score_5'] < $low_score_5) ? $row['low_score_5'] : $low_score_5;
    $low_score_6 = ($row['low_score_6'] < $low_score_6) ? $row['low_score_6'] : $low_score_6;
    $low_score_7 = ($row['low_score_7'] < $low_score_7) ? $row['low_score_7'] : $low_score_7;
    $low_score_8 = ($row['low_score_8'] < $low_score_8) ? $row['low_score_8'] : $low_score_8;

}

// lowest of the entire set
$t = array($low_score_1,$low_score_2,$low_score_3,$low_score_4,
            $low_score_5,$low_score_6,$low_score_7,$low_score_8)

echo min($t);
```

Or you could do

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $low1[] = $row['low_score_1'];
    $low2[] = $row['low_score_2'];
    $low3[] = $row['low_score_3'];
    $low4[] = $row['low_score_4'];
    $low5[] = $row['low_score_5'];
    $low6[] = $row['low_score_6'];
    $low7[] = $row['low_score_7'];
    $low8[] = $row['low_score_8'];  
}

$low_score_1 = min($low1);
$low_score_2 = min($low2);
$low_score_3 = min($low3);
$low_score_4 = min($low4);
$low_score_5 = min($low5);
$low_score_6 = min($low6);
$low_score_7 = min($low7);
$low_score_8 = min($low8);

// lowest of the entire set
$t = array($low_score_1,$low_score_2,$low_score_3,$low_score_4,
            $low_score_5,$low_score_6,$low_score_7,$low_score_8);

echo min($t);
```

Comment: So from that, how would i echo out the lowest value from the entire set?

Comment: What, you mean the lowest of all 8 low scores

Comment: All I want to do is look at all 8 scores or put them into an array, find out which number is the lowest and output it

Comment: Sorry, I think you will have to draw me a picture

Comment: my code just outputs a value for each row. so like 1, 2.5, 3, 2, 3.75, 1.5, 2, 2.75 but i want to look at those values and then find out which one is the lowest and show only that value

Comment: Found it was a missing `;`